# Generic Xpath in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium Webdriver. I have been using Firebug & Firepath to generate xpath (copy pasting the given xpath) for the web elements, but I am facing problems when using such xpaths(Such as "Xpath cannot be evaluated into an web elemnt").

Please help me with the below example of xpath of a Webelement to create a flexible & generic xpath:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" length="40" value="" name="ST_ACK_NUM"/>
```

Comment: Don't use the **absolute** `xpath` you get from `firebug`, a minor change to the `html` may make the `xpath` no longer work.

Comment: Hi. It's a very bad idea using the xpath generated by firepath because firepath generates xpath based on positions. Check out this blog http://www.guru99.com/accessing-links-tables-selenium-webdriver.html provides some good info on xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the people say in the comments it is better to create a more **relative** path to your elements. Maybe you can post some more input so the XPath can be created more efficiently.

To get the input with a absolute XPath you can do:

```
 //input[@name='ST_ACK_NUM']
```

Above XPath will search the complete source to all `<input>` elements where attribute `name` equals the value `ST_ACK_NUM`

When you look at your source maybe you can adjust the XPath and add more dependencies. For example if your input looks like:

```
 <div class="DivClass">
   <form name="FormName">
     <input type="text" maxlength="15" length="40" value="" name="ST_ACK_NUM"/>
   </form>
 </div>
```

You could use a XPath like:

```
 //div[@class='DivClass']/form[@name='FormName']/input[@name='ST_ACK_NUM']
```

This will also find the `<input>` element, but with a lot more dependencies.

Comment: Pfff indeed :S. Adjusted comment